# Type does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' or "Encodable"

Tags: swift, codable

Im fairly new to programming and I fixed a few errors but only one error ist left, which states: Type 'DataClass' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' and Type 'DataClass' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable' on line 14.

I checked smiliar questions but I'm not fairly sure if i can find a solution if i put init

```
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome1: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let entityType, label: String
    let apiURL, abgeordnetenwatchURL: String
    let firstName, lastName: String
    let birthName: String
    let sex: String
    let yearOfBirth: Int
    // let party: Referenz -> Party???
    let partyPast: String
    let education: String
    let residence: String
    let occupation: String
    let statisticQuestions: Int
    let statisticQuestionsAnswered: Int
    let qidWikidata, fieldTitle: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case entityType = "entity_type"
        case label = "label"
        case apiURL = "api_url"
        case abgeordnetenwatchURL = "abgeordnetenwatch_url"
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case birthName = "birth_name"
        case sex = "sex"
        case yearOfBirth = "year_of_birth"
        case party = "party"
        case partyPast = "party_past"
        case education = "education"
        case residence = "residence"
        case occupation = "occupation"
        case statisticQuestions = "statistic_questions"
        case statisticQuestionsAnswered = "statistic_questions_answered"
        case qidWikidata = "qid_wikidata"
        case fieldTitle = "field_title"
    }
}

// MARK: - Party
struct Party1: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let entityType, label: String
    let apiURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case entityType = "entity_type"
        case label
        case apiURL = "api_url"
    }
}
```

I am trying to use Json parser to collect data from this site [lingk](https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians). I used [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) recommended by a tutorial.

Comment: Replace the line `// let party: Referenz -> Party???` with `let party: Party1`. And you can get rid of all CodingKeys if you apply the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy. And according to the JSON `data` is an array you have to decode `[DataClass]`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove
`case party = "party"` line

or open

`// let party: Referenz -> Party?` line

Comment: ohhhh! i fixied it! Thank you! I thought I commented it out so it had no influence to the code..